# May I post a possibly non-coding question when we have a tag for the topic?

Tags: support, scope

After I posted [my question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296997/where-to-ask-question-when-so-has-tag-but-question-seems-off-topic), I was redirected here to ask this:

Would a question about *JasperSoft ReportsServer Authentification Priorities* be off-topic on Stack Overflow? There is a [jasperserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasperserver) tag, but it seems off-topic to me, as it hasn't anything to do with coding (except you consider adjusting XML files as coding).

Comment: This question may create a bit of contention, as it falls into a grey area of when questions about software development-related tooling are on-topic or not; they can be given the right circumstances, most notably that it is a problem that has to do with the software development process. Generally the answer to these high level questions is "maybe", you'd need to ask about a specific question that can be presented here to judge if that question is on-topic or not.

Comment: @Gimby As Petter answered me I guess I will just give it a try in the specific section of SO. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"adjusting XMLs"* is coding!, that basically what we do all day in the [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) tag.

The tag's to use are [jasperserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasperserver) and [jasper-reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jasper-reports).

Note: That I can't understand exactly what your question is, so also check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more information on how to stay on-topic.

**Conclusion:**

Post the question, if it has problems we will try to help you to edit it into shape, if we can't get into to shape we will help you to close it.

Comment: Your welcome, remember it's a low traffic tag (few user answering and asking), so you will need some patience and luck to get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I´ll keep this in mind describe my problem with precision :)